# Sending email with ssmtp From value issue

Tags: email, bash, ssmtp

I am trying to send an email from my cron script using ssmtp, the email is working fine but the "From" value is always showing `Ubuntu <ubuntu@example.com>` which I don't want to use because I need to use something like `From="Cron Report <no-reply@example.com>"`,

**ssmtp.conf**

```
#
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=postmaster

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=####################

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
#rewriteDomain=

# The full hostname
hostname=example.com
AuthUser=####################
AuthPass==####################
FromLineOverride=NO
UseSTARTTLS=YES
#From="Cron Report <no-reply@example.com>"


# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
#FromLineOverride=YES
```

**revaliases**

```
root:no-reply@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to change the settings in the config, but the below worked for me.

1). Uncomment ssmtp.conf:

```
FromLineOverride=YES
```

and in the crontab itself, specify 'from' address (not the below will send an email every 5 minutes ;):

```
MAILTO=<my-address@example.com>
MAILFROM=<cron-sender@example.com>
*/5 * * * * echo 'Test email from crontab. Skynet takes over the world!'
```